# htaccess regexp matching all except string or extension

Tags: regex, .htaccess

In my `.htaccess` file I have the following line that prevents file injection:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
```

I would like to add an exception to accept requests starting with `image=` and ending with `.jpg` or `.png`.

I thought of doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!(image)$)=http:// [OR]
```

It doesn't work

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http://[^.jpg|.png]
```

didn't work either

What I'd like to achieve is to block anything for the query string and its value except `image=http://some_url.jpg(or .png)`

Any idea of how I could do this without taking additional risks?

Comment: Sure you can find the full list of expressions used here:

Comment: https://secure.rivalhost.com/knowledgebase/1037/htaccess-against-MySQL-injections-and-other-hacks.html

Comment: Sure, I'd like to allow ?image=http://www.example.com/image.jpg (or . jpg) but should I want to change image one day, I should be able to adapt the rule so basically something (image|somethingElse)=http://www.example.com/image(.jpg|.png)

Comment: I'd like to blocking anything else containing a url like ?test=http://www.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'd like to achieve is to block anything for the query string and its value except `image=http://some_url.jpg(or .png)`

So, you need to match that in order to proceed. It really depends on how strict you want to be in matching `<some_url>`.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^image=http://[a-z0-9.-]+/[\w/.-]\.(jpg|png)$
```

This doesn't allow any "special" characters in the URL, just your regular a-z, A-Z, 0-9, slash, dot and hypen.

**UPDATE:** To block (403 Forbidden) any request that contains what looks like a URL in the query string but does *not* fit the above pattern then try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https?://. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^image=http://[a-z0-9.-]+/[\w/.-]\.(jpg|png)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

In this example, "looks like a URL" is simply if it contains `http://` or `https://`.

> starting with `image=` and ending with `.jpg` or `.png`.

If you want to be more liberal then try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^image=.+\.(jpg|png)$
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
> ```

Not quite sure of the intention with this one, but `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` would only match a single character.

Comment: Hello W3DK, thanks! Your first answer works fine but I realised that I was missing something. What I would like in the end is prevent injections so anything that looks like an url should be blocked except the combination of the image query and the .jpg or .png ending. Would you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Fantastic, it works! Should I also cover cases where there is no http and only a www. or ftp. ? RewriteCOnd %{QUERY_STRING} (www|ftp).?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what your application is doing with this. Simply passing URLs in the query string doesn't necessarily result in "file injections". Regardless of what you do in `.htaccess` you should still validate the input in your application. If your application expects an absolute URL but there is no "http(s)" scheme in the passed data then it's not a URL.

Comment: There should be an `NC` flag on the first `RewriteCond` directive - I've updated my answer.